# neo4j browser doesn't visualize pro

Tags: neo4j

I made two node and one relationship
node: Person(Sally, John) and book(gdp) relation: `HAS_READ`
and I wanted to see "sally-HAS_READ->gdp", "John-HAS_READ->gdp
but when I wrote `MATCH p=(n:Person)-[r:HAS_READ]->() RETURN n,p LIMIT 25` then there is only (no changes, no records)

If I wrote `MATCH p=()-[r:HAS_READ]->() RETURN p LIMIT 25`, then I can see entire entities and relation edge but entities was not clear. I can't figure out which one is john or sally, it was just gray color.

If I want to clear entity and relation edges, How could I do?
ex) John -HAS_READ->gdp

Comment: Please show us how you created the two nodes and one relationship so that we can confirm that the data is loaded correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the first query returned no results then you should check if your person nodes, Sally and John really have a `Person` label on them.

To the second part of your question, you can customise the property displayed in the visualisation. In your query results visualisation, click on the Label badge like this
[image]
and at the bottom you'll see how to pick a colour and property and so on

[image]

You can remove a node by clicking on it and removing it like so:
[image]

Comment: thank you for answering. But when I did clicking it, nodes(Sally, John) just disappeared.